# pySpark read from multiple source and load into multiple tables

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-emr

I have Archiecture as below

Source 1 --> EMR (Spark transformation) -->  into Snowflake Tables A,B,C

Source 2 --> EMR (Spark transformation) -->  into Snowflake  Tables D,E,F

Source 3 --> EMR (Spark transformation) -->  into Snowflake. Table  G,H
....
..
.
.

I have 27 sources like this, can I write all transformations in a single spark program and use a single EMR. All sources need to be triggered parallel and loaded parallelly into snowflake.